# Getting an Access Violation on SpawnActor() function in UE5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

so I am following a tutorial and so far so good but I am unable to resolve or understand why I am getting an Access Violation error even though the guy in the tutorial doesn't get this error.

It's a custom weapon class that I am trying to spawn:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FIKProperties
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

};

UCLASS(Abstract)

class WEHRMACHTCSMP_API AWeapon : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AWeapon();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
};
```

Here is the code I call the spawn function:

```
    void AWMPlayerCharacter::BeginPlay()
    {
        Super::BeginPlay();
    
        if (HasAuthority())
        {
            for (const TSubclassOf<AWeapon>& WeaponClass : DefaultWeapons)
            {
                if (!WeaponClass) continue;
                FActorSpawnParameters Params;
          
                AWeapon* SpawnedWeapon;
    
                SpawnedWeapon = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AWeapon>(WeaponClass, Params);  <--- ACCESS VIOLATION
    
                const int32 Index = Weapons.Add(SpawnedWeapon);
                CurrentWeapon = SpawnedWeapon;
                OnRep_CurrentWeapon(nullptr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is screenshot in Visual Studio of where it fails:

https://i.imgur.com/OOVIoOU.png

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `GetWorld()` returns `nullptr`. You should use your favourite debugger to examine what happens.

Comment: It returns valid data so it's not it..

Comment: There's definitely a null pointer somewhere. Without a [mre] you'll have to debug it yourself

Comment: How have you verified the validity of GetWorld? That’s almost certainly the correct answer. In the event it isn’t then you can either try removing/swapping bits until it works. Or build the engine from source in full debug mode to get a clearer picture out of the debugger.

Comment: @kepler425b
`GetWorld()` might return valid data but that does not mean it's really valid. This is because in Unreal Engine you are supposed to use `IsValid` for all `UObject`s. One of the more common mistakes is to just check for pointer validity (as we are taught in C++) and assume the object is valid.

Comment: @Samaursa That’s just not true. IsValid does have some extra checks. But either a pointer is null or it’s not as far as a pointer access violation goes.

Comment: @George Sorry, but you're wrong in this case. Those extra checks are whether it's pending kill or already garbaged. It is a _very_ common issue when programmers add `nullptr` checks instead of doing `IsValid` and find out that they eventually invoked undefined behavior because the object is **no longer valid as far as Unreal is concerned**. Unreal's GC has marked the object as garbage. Whether it is `nullptr` or not is irrelevant unless you know what you're doing and are careful with what you access and how you pass it around.